# Update jeditable text field after checking security

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jeditable

I've got a scenario where only some users have permission to update a field.  I'm trying to put jEditable in place to allow in place editing of the field, and want to check the permissions on the back end in the controller as follows:

```
 public JsonResult UpdateComment(string MRN, string comment)
 {
    if (this.HttpContext.User.CanComment())
    {
        return this.Json(new 
           { 
             Status = "OK", 
             value = this.service.UpdateComment(MRN, comment) 
           });
    }

    return this.Json(new { //???? });
}
```

My View looks like:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.DetailViewModel
<div>
    ....
    <span id="txtSource">@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.Source)</span>
    <span id="txtMRN">@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.MRN)</span>
    <span id="@Model.CommentIdName">@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.Comments)</span>
    ....
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#editComment').editable("/@Model.Source/UpdateComment",
            {
                id: 'mrn',
                name: 'comment',
                type: 'textarea',
                cancel: 'Cancel',
                submit: ' OK',
                tooltip: 'Click to Edit Comment...'
            });
    });
</script>
```

In the situation where the user doesn't have permission to 'Comment', the edit needs to be canceled, and the field value returned to its original value.

I've already setup in my view to change the id of the field to something that jEditable isn't looking for when the view is rendered, so that takes care of most scenarios without having to deal with it on the back end.

I'm trying to protect the data and return a reasonable response, and I don't know what code is needed in place of the comment //????'.

**Edit:**

Fixed javascript problem and simplified it by putting it into the view.

Comment: I also need to say that one of my constraints is that all accesses of the record details must be logged. (I'll log the Edit in the 'UpdateComment' service call.)  I don't want to go access the details again to return the original 'comment', what I want is to somehow force jEditable to Cancel the edit when the user is unauthorized.